# sending a list from asp.net to Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I have a list of object that is created in my asp.net website project, I need to send it to my silverlight application which is a part of the same solution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should answer your question:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article218.aspx